# How does RMI locate classes when objects are downloaded where a class file does not exist locally?

Tags: java, rmi

i'm struggling to understand how RMI locates classes when objects are downloaded where a class file does not exist locally?

Comment: What is there to understand exactly? You're aware of the feature, you know what it does ... are you asking how it works?

Comment: The question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI can communicate both objects *and their classes*.

If a class is not available in the local codebase, it can be downloaded from a URL, and loaded by a special class loader.

See this tutorial on [RMI code downloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html).